# Creating a 3d level from real world room

Tags: unreal, level-design, 3d-modeling

I'm doing a project simulating autonomous drone flights inside buildings and I was asked to provide a level which is modeled after one of the floors in our faculty building.
I was given a pdf which contains 2d plans made with autocad 2014 and has layers.
Unfortunately I don't have any knowledge on how to use those plans or read them.
Is there some sort of way to model a real let's say corridor into unreal engine?
preferably using photos or something like that but every method is fine as long as it works.

Thanks

Comment: Searching "3d model room from photos" is turning up quite a few guides on the first page of results. Which ones have you tried following so far, and where have you run into trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of ways to create 3D models into (or to import into) Unreal:

- A very basic solution is to use the **[BSP Brushes](https://www.worldofleveldesign.com/categories/ue4/bsp-01-what-is-bsp.php)** in Unreal Engine, it’s actually a system designed to block out a level, for rapid prototyping, but it might suit your needs very well!
- A little more complex solution is the new **[Mesh Tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSzk2osk2Ms)** plugin that has been introduced in Unreal Engine, to let you model a Mesh in a more detailed way.
- For the most advanced solution you can make 3D models in [**Blender**](https://www.blender.org/), a free full-fledged 3D Software, and use your PDF with Autocad plans to ensure the right proportions in Blender. After the modeling part is done, simply import it into Unreal Engine with the .FBX File Format. You can add or apply texture (photos) to your model as well.
- If you have or can extract your Autocad Plans and you would like to use them as references, then you can import them into **[Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l55f7gbtz1Q)** or Unreal Engine (with **[DataSmith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW_00xWZNIE)**)

Good luck with your project!